# What's the difference between those methods in writing jQuery code

Tags: jquery

Hello i want to know the difference between writing the prependTo() with those methods and which one is better

first method:

```
$("<h1></h1>",
{
    text:"Login",
    class:"title"
}).prependTo("body");
```

second method:

```
$("<h1 class='title'>Login</h1>").prependTo("body");
```

Comment: Both will do the same thing. I personally prefer first approach as it is much cleaner. However I think second one will be faster (need to test)

Comment: Thanks thats why i asked the question because i see the first one is cleaner and nice

Comment: You should reword your question as this is not really specific to `prependTo()`

Comment: I Think its global one yeah you are right

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference with `prependTo` in the example you have provided, the difference is with how you are creating the jQuery object.

The first approach passes the relevant attributes into the constructor whereas the second simply embeds them into the HTML. I would assume the first approach is more optimal from a jQuery point of view because it doesn't have to parse the attributes out of the HTML.

Ultimately there is no difference in both examples, the end result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

On the first way, you explicit set the html attributes,  so that means that your h1 will have those attributes (class and text), and this way, its easier to replace those values with variables and maintain the code.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

On the second one, you are prepend an HTML String, a jQuery type.

http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString

I personally recommend the first one, because its easier to maintain.